# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined. Ayuda php 7

Tags: php

Recientemente me cambie a php 7, estoy haciendo las modificaciones a un sistema de registro de usuarios a la versión php 7. Pero me he topado con un error que no logro dar que es. tengo una función de agregaDatos para que me aparezcan los datos que tengo en mi base de datos y el usuario pueda modificar esta información, pero no se cual sea mi error o que haya cambiado con la nueva versión, por que si lo pruebo con php 5, funciona bien, pero al ponerlo en php 7 me manda este error Uncaught ReferenceError: agregaDatos not defined

Aqui esta mi funcion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function agregaDatos(datos){
d = datos.split('||');
p_idUsuario = d[0];
p_clave = d[1];
p_nombre = d[2]; 
$("#txtIdUsuarioEd").val(p_idUsuario);
$("#txtNombreEd").val(p_nombre);
$("#txtClaveEd").val(p_clave);
}
</script>
```

y aqui esta mi funcion donde la llamo:

```
public function listaDeUsuarios($link){
$sql="select idUsuario, clave, nombreUsuario from admusuarios order by nombreUsuario ";
$resultadoQry = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
echo '<table class="table table-hover table-sm table-striped">';
echo '<tr>';
echo    '<th>Usuario</th>';
echo    '<th class="text-center">Edición</th>';
echo    '<th class="text-center">Permisos de menú</th>';
echo    '<th class="text-center">Eliminar</th>';
echo '</tr>';
while ($admusuarios=mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoQry, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $datos="'".
    $admusuarios["idUsuario"]."||".
    $admusuarios["clave"]."||".
    $admusuarios["nombreUsuario"]."'";

    echo '<tr class="usuario">';
    echo    '<td><span class=" grpUsuarios">'.trim($admusuarios["nombreUsuario"]).'</span></td>';
    **echo    '<td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditaUsuario" onclick="agregaDatos('.$datos.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button></td>';**
    echo    '<td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOpciones" onclick="agregaDatosAlFormOpciones('.$datos.')"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>';
    if ($admusuarios["nombreUsuario"]==$_SESSION["nombreUsuario"]){ $oculto="invisible";} else {$oculto="";}
    echo    '<td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger '.$oculto.'" onclick="confirmaEliminaUsuario('.$datos.')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

podrian ayudarme por favor!!

Gracias!!!

Comment: no veo nada de código Java y por eso quité esa etiqueta, saludos

Comment: Ya te aseguraste que cargue completamente la página antes de que llame a la función `agregarDatos()`?

Comment: si, carga la pagina completamente antes de que llame a la función, este error solo me pasa si cambio a la versión php 7, por que si ponga la version 5, no tengo este error

Answer (score 0):

eso es porque estas en php, es decir llamando desde un archivo php a una funcion javascript.

primero no veo la necesidad de php tenes html y llamas a una funcion javascript saca el php o usa una funcion de php.
segundo te recomiendo un motor de plantillas como twig o blade te ahorra tener que escribir html en un echo que para debuggear es muy complicado.